# unable to move header to center even align is centered

Tags: html

I need to move personal account to center and gave align as centre but still not working. I don't have any clue where am lagging.

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="750" align="center" bgColor="#000000" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="750" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr>
          <td width="34%" bgcolor="#ff0000" colspan="5">
            <div class="mainheader">Personal &amp; Account
            </div>
          </td>
          <td width="33%" bgcolor="#ff0000">
            <div align="right">
              <button class="button" id="btnLogin" accessKey="P" type="button" runat="server">Login&nbsp;</button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like you missed adding your code or it is not properly formatted.

Comment: Don't use tables for layout -- use them for tabular data

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as mentioned in the comment by *j08691*, try avoiding tables for layout.

For a solution to your issue, I'll keep your tabular layout as I want to keep up with your question's code, but here's a solution which starts with removing the second inner `td` - as you dont need it for floating the button to the right side.

I've changed your two columns to one column and inside of this column inserted a `div` with the desired layout - a text in the middle and a button in the right side.

The button is floated right by `"float: right;"` and the text is aligned to the center of the `div` by `"text-align: center"`. Try using the same approach for future layout design.

[Here is a working example with the below code:](http://codepen.io/Alon_A/pen/oYOvWd)

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="750" align="center" bgColor="#000000" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="750" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr>
          <td width="34%" bgcolor="#ff0000" colspan="5">
            <div class="mainheader" style="text-align: center">Personal &amp; Account
               <button class="button" id="btnLogin" accesskey="P" type="button" runat="server" style="float: right;">Login&nbsp;</button>            
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Alon_A but that didn't worked out. Rather I used a style tag next to mainheader class in div section  <style = "margin-left:175px;"> Here is what I tried

Comment: @saireddy Indeed, there are multiple ways for a solution, my modification works in [the provided example](http://codepen.io/Alon_A/pen/oYOvWd), why it didn't work for you ? Anyway, I'm happy you reached a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
<td  bgcolor="#1f4e79" colspan="5">
                                <div class="mainheader" style="margin-left:325px;"  >Restraint &amp; Seclusion
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="33%" bgcolor="#1f4e79">
                                    <div align="right">
                                        <button class="button" id="btnLogin" accessKey="P" type="button" runat="server">Login&nbsp;</button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
```